# How to send receive file through RabbitMQ queue in C#?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I need to send and receive file through queue using RabbitMQ. I didn't get any solution to send files directly, so I am using the below code and planned to read the file and send the file data to the receiver. But I dont think its good approach. There may be better approaches.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

            var body = File.ReadAllBytes("SomePath");

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
```

Also there is one limitation in this code, I cannot pass the file name in data directly. So I thought two approaches for this.

1. Convert the file name in byte array and append with file data byte array. and at client side extract the file name from byte array.
2. Make two calls, one to send file name and second to send the file data and at receiver create the same file using file name and file data.

Please let me know if there are better approaches to send and receive files.

Comment: Would it not be better to pass a reference to a file, rather than the file itself?

Comment: both application can be on different machines as well

Comment: see [this](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2019-05-24-what-is-the-message-size-limit-in-rabbitmq.html) large messages can cause performance issues.

Comment: @Slappywag link in not accessible, giving 404 error. given that files are small only. by the way what is max data limit?

Comment: @Slappywag consider files are small only. For large files what are the alternatives?

Comment: @viveknuna How did you end up implementing this?

Comment: @Valu3 I followed first approach